# Security Incident File Change Timestamp

Tags: linux, audit

How can I obtain all timestamps of all files ( starting"/") on a Linux system in order to verify if a file was changed within a breach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly and you want to get all files in Linux and their associated timestamps:

```
find / -printf '%Tc %p\n'
```

beware of date stomping tho.